# Docker Container from Image not recongizing env variable inside React Application even thought they can be echo in Docker Container

Tags: reactjs, docker, environment-variables

I am experiencing something weird, I am trying to implement CI/CD in my React Application to push code as an image in Docker Hub, but when I try to pull it and run it using env variables, even though that env variables are with Prefix REACT_APP, they come as undefined in the frontend, but for some reason, they are stored in the container because I did echo, and it prints.
On the other hand, if I just build the dockerimage locally not by pulling the image (run the dockerfile) the env variables are stored correctly.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder
# Set the working directory to /app inside the container
WORKDIR /app
# Copy app files
COPY . .
# Install dependencies (npm ci makes sure the exact versions in the lockfile gets installed)
RUN npm ci 
# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Bundle static assets with nginx
FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine as production
ENV NODE_ENV production
# Copy built assets from `builder` image
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
# Add your nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Expose port
EXPOSE 80
# Start nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Nginx.conf (is in root as a file not inside nginx folder)

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

.github/workflows/docker-image.yml

```
name: Push Backend as Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["master"]

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: dummy-frontend/test:latest
```

.env

```
REACT_APP_URL=url
REACT_APP_API_URL=url
REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL=url
REACT_APP_NAME=app_name
```

code example:

```
    {process.env.REACT_APP_NAME === null || process.env.REACT_APP_NAME === undefined
        ? "undefined"
        : process.env.REACT_APP_NAME}
```

When I run the app locally not through docker pull but from the docker file, these are the commands (it displayed the react app name):

```
docker build . -t dockerized-react

docker run -p 3000:80 --env-file .env -d dockerized-react
```

When I run the app locally through docker pull, these are the commands (that env variable comes as undefined, but I am able to echo the env variables through the container):

```
docker run -p 3000:80 --env-file .env -d dummy-frontend/test:latest
```

Here it comes as undefined.

I am not understanding where is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you are building your React application, [it inlines the value of environment variables into the static JavaScript bundle that it produces](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). That happens during *build* time, not at run time.

That is why the environment variables are undefined in your Docker container because they were not present during the build process (the one done by the GitHub Action).

When you are building your Docker image on your local machine, you have the [`.env` file present](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/), so the environment variables are correctly inlined into the static bundle.

However, when you are building your Docker image using GitHub Actions, the environment variables are not present because your Dockerfile shows you are not copying them into the Docker image. Therefore, they are not available at build time and cannot be inlined into the bundle.

You could consider building your React application at run time.
But…, this will significantly increase your container startup time, as your React application will need to be built every time your container is started.

I would prefer including your environment variables when building your Docker image on GitHub Actions.
You could use GitHub Actions secrets to store your environment variables, and then pass them into the `docker/build-push-action` step of your workflow using the `build-args` input.

```yaml
- name: Build and push Docker image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
  with:
      context: .
      push: true
      tags: dummy-frontend/test:latest
      build-args: |
        REACT_APP_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_URL }}
        REACT_APP_API_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_URL }}
        REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL }}
        REACT_APP_NAME=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_NAME }}
```

That way, your environment variables will be available at build time and can be inlined into your static React bundle.

Again, do replace the placeholders in the `secrets` syntax with the actual names of your GitHub secrets.

However, this will build your Docker image with the environment variables inlined into the static bundle, so the same Docker image cannot be used with different environment variables.

Lastly, do not forget to add the `ARG` instruction in your Dockerfile for each build argument:

```
# ...
ARG REACT_APP_URL
ARG REACT_APP_API_URL
ARG REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL
ARG REACT_APP_NAME
# ...
```

Those instructions are to be placed *before* the `npm run build` command.

---

> 

But in fact, I wanted to run those on the docker container, I mean the `ENV` attributes because on GitHub I do not think is very much safe. Is there a chance to edit those when running the container?

If you want to use different environment variables when you run the container, you will need to make some modifications to the way your application is served.

Because environment variables are inlined at build time in React, you will not be able to change them at runtime in the traditional way. See also [**React environment variables: A developer’s guide**](https://www.architect.io/blog/2022-08-16/react-environment-variables-developers-guide/) by [Lee Brandt](https://twitter.com/leebrandt).

However, there is a workaround.

One common approach is to have a server-side script that runs when your container starts up, which generates a JavaScript file containing your environment variables. That file can then be included in your HTML, allowing your JavaScript code to access the environment variables.

Add a script in your public folder (let's call it `env-config.js`):

```js
window._env_ = {
  REACT_APP_URL: "default",
  REACT_APP_API_URL: "default",
  REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL: "default",
  REACT_APP_NAME: "default",
}
```

Include the script in `public/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/env-config.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Update your JavaScript code to use `window._env_` instead of `process.env`:

```js
{
  window._env_.REACT_APP_NAME === null || window._env_.REACT_APP_NAME === undefined
    ? "undefined"
    : window._env_.REACT_APP_NAME
}
```

And add a script in your Dockerfile that generates `env-config.js` at runtime:

Here is an example using a shell script, `scripts/env.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# Stop script on errors
set -e

# Recreate config file
rm -rf ./public/env-config.js
touch ./public/env-config.js

# Add assignment 
echo "window._env_ = {" >> ./public/env-config.js

# Read each line in .env file
# Each line represents key=value pairs
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];
do
  if printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep -q -e '=';
  then
    varname=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -e 's/=.*//')
    varvalue=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//')
    echo "  $varname: \"$varvalue\"," >> ./public/env-config.js
  fi
done < .env

echo "}" >> ./public/env-config.js
```

Then you can call this script at container startup. The Dockerfile might look like this:

```
# ...
# Add your nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Copy env.sh
COPY scripts/env.sh /usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh
# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh
# Expose port
EXPOSE 80
# Start nginx
CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\"" ]
```

Now, when you run your container, you can pass in environment variables, and they will be picked up by your application:

```bash
docker run -p 3000:80 --env-file .env -d dummy-frontend/test:latest
```

That means your environment variables are not baked into your Docker image, meaning the same image can be used in different environments. And, because the environment variables are inserted into the HTML at runtime, they can be changed simply by restarting the Docker container with different variables.

It does, however, expose your environment variables in the source code of your HTML, so it should not be used for sensitive variables. If you need to use sensitive variables, consider making a server-side call to a secure endpoint that can return your variables instead.

You have also "**[Making environment variables accessible in front-end container](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/03/04/making-environment-variables-accessible-in-front-end-containers#)**" from [Joel Lord](https://github.com/joellord) as an alternative approach.

Comment: But in fact, I wanted to run those on the docker container, I mean the ENV attributes, because on GitHub I do not think is very much safe.
Is there a chance to edit those when running the container?

Comment: in scripts/env.sh edit #!/bin/bash >> #!/bin/sh for not getting error: file not found

Comment: @MiBe Thank you for your feedback. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer are already detailed when it comes to explaining why there is a problem. However, I want to suggest an alternative solution.

You can write the variables at runtime into a JS file and import that in your React app. That way, you don't need to know during build time what values it should have. In my opinion, the build time technique is against the container spirit.

So a simple implementation could look like this.

1. You create an entrypoint script for your container. In that entrypoint you pick up the env variables and write them to a minimalistic JS file.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -ex

cat <<EOF >/usr/share/nginx/html/runtime/vars.js
export default {
  url: "${REACT_APP_URL:-some-default-url}",
  apiUrl: "${REACT_APP_API_URL:-other-default-url}",
};
EOF
```

When using nginx, you can add this script to `entrypoint.d`.

```rb
COPY --chmod=0755 entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/
```

2. Now you can add some code to your JavaScript app to import the file, and use it in your app.

For example

```js
import injects from './runtime/vars.js';

function Welcome(props) {
  return <a href="{props.url}">Example</a>;
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
const element = <Welcome url=injects.url />;
root.render(element);
```

> **Note** I am not a react dev, so that code is really just to give the rough idea. You probably know better how and where to pass the variables.