# Env variable not recognized when building a docker container of React Vite App

Tags: reactjs, docker, environment-variables, vite

I am facing a weird problem, I have this .env

```
REACT_APP_URL=http://localhost:8080
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:4500/api
REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL='URL'
REACT_APP_NAME=NAME
REACT_APP_GA_TRACKING_ID=
```

If I run the application using `npm start`, the variables are recognized correctly.

If I also try to run the docker build locally without pulling the image from the docker hub, the variables are working correctly. These are the commands:

```
docker build . -t container
docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file .env -d --name container--restart always container
```

They are recognized and the application runs with the variables.

```
This is the dockerfile:

FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "run", "preview" ]
```

On the same time, every time I push on master I push the app in dockerhub.
And in this scenario, the variables are not recognized:

```
docker pull user/repository_test
docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file .env -d --name repo --restart always user/repository_test
```

The variables are not recognized, how is that possible? I can see however in docker in inspect that the variables are passed in the container but on react not recognized.

[image: The inspect from docker container, where env variables are not recognized]

On the image on top, is the inspect from docker container, where env variables are not recognized, but they are stored on the container.

Comment: I feel like there is something wrong with your last command, isn't the `container` parameter too much ? Shouldn't it be `docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file .env -d --name repo --restart always user/repository_test` ?

Comment: @ABWassim Sorry that was a typo on my command, it is like you said and still does not work.

Comment: This question looks very similar to the question you've asked in July - [Docker Container from Image not recongizing env variable inside React Application even thought they can be echo in Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76699270/docker-container-from-image-not-recongizing-env-variable-inside-react-applicatio?rq=2). Given that your Dockerfile doesn't seem to have the suggestions from the answer, I guess this could be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76699270/6309), you are now using a [React Vite application](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) (as opposed to [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) before). And you now are more about a discrepancy between local Docker builds where the environment variables are recognized, and Docker Hub builds where they are not.

As I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76718158/6309), environment variables in React are embedded during the build process, not at runtime. That means, if the variables are not available at the time of building the Docker image, they will not be present when the application is running.

From the Dockerfile and the workflow you have shared, the build process on GitHub Actions is not using any environment variables. Therefore, when the application is built, the environment variables are not embedded into the build.

To fix this, you need to make sure environment variables are available at build time when the Docker image is built in your CI/CD pipeline. You can use [build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/build-args/) to pass environment variables during the Docker build process in your GitHub Actions workflow.

```yaml
# previous steps

- name: Build and push Docker image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: user/repository_test:latest
    build-args: |
      REACT_APP_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_URL }}
      REACT_APP_API_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_URL }}
      REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL }}
      REACT_APP_NAME=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_NAME }}
```

And in your Dockerfile, you should declare these arguments before the build step:

And in your Dockerfile, you should declare these arguments before the build step:

```
# previous content

ARG REACT_APP_URL
ARG REACT_APP_API_URL
ARG REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL
ARG REACT_APP_NAME

# Use the ARGs as environment variables
ENV REACT_APP_URL=$REACT_APP_URL
ENV REACT_APP_API_URL=$REACT_APP_API_URL
ENV REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL=$REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL
ENV REACT_APP_NAME=$REACT_APP_NAME

RUN npm run build

# remaining content
```

You can set the actual environment variables in the secrets of your GitHub repository.

That way, your environment variables will be included during the build process, and your React application will have access to them when it is running inside the Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the game but another option is, within your Dockerfile, simply copy your .env file (make sure it's not mentioned in your .dockerignore) to the public folder within your app before executing npm run build:

```
COPY ./.env /app/public/.env

RUN npm install && npm run build
```

This way your .env file is available in your container and your app will read it at container start. Advantage of this scheme is you don't need to duplicate all your .env entries as --build-args when building your container.